# Query equals check with 1-3 row result prefers NonClustered Index Scan

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Here is my table which has order_number column. The table has less than 500 rows at the moment. A non clustered index on order_number has been created.

```
CREATE TABLE [outbound_service].[shipment_line]
(
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [shipment_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [order_number] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    .... 18 other columns

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SHIPMENT_LINE] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [uk_order_order_line_number] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([order_number] ASC, [order_line_number] ASC)
               WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_shipment_line_order 
    ON outbound_service.shipment_line(order_number ASC)
```

Here is my simple equals check query that might return at max 5 rows.

```
DECLARE @P0 nvarchar(400) ='LG-ORD-002';

SELECT TOP 1 sl.order_number 
FROM outbound_service.shipment_line sl
WHERE sl.order_number = @P0
```

I have expected nonclustered index seek, but I see an index scan happening. Very limited data at max 5 rows per `order_number`:

[image]

If I run the query without bind parameters, I see the index seek:

[image]

I have another database where I expect millions of rows and am worried about this scan as it is leading to 100 CPU on this query with high concurrency and slowing down rest of the workflows.

What could be the reason here when the data to return from index is very minimal but still SQL Server seems to be liking scan instead of seek?

Comment: What kind of query did you write a store procedure or query with parameters?

Comment: Could you use `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` show us logical read from both queries?

Comment: If you only insert 5 rows, the whole table sits in a single page of data. Indexes are paged too, so whichever query plan is used, a single page is read. To profile a query's behaviour, you need to insert a representative amount of data in a representative way (mixture of inserts, updates, deletes, etc). There are whole books on this, so I can't fit it in a comment. Just search the Web for SQL Server Performance Profiling. Also, you MUST specify an ORDER BY to tell the optimiser whqt you mean by TOP 1, it doesn't "innately" mean "max value".

Comment: Since your column `order_number` is of type `[varchar](255)`, in your first sample, you should also make your search variable the same type - try with `DECLARE @P0 varchar(255) = 'LG-ORD-002';` - does that make any difference??

Answer (score 2):

There is a `convert_implicit` from your first execution plan, I would always align parameter type as column type and size, in addition, if you want to get the result by `top` I would suggest using `ORDER BY order_number` for two reasons.

1. A non-clustered index `IX_shipment_line_order` might be chosen to use without sorting cost.
2. Without `order by` we might not guarantee the result as you expect if you use TOP.

As this query

```
DECLARE @P0 [varchar](255) ='LG-ORD-002';

SELECT TOP 1 sl.order_number 
FROM outbound_service.shipment_line sl
WHERE sl.order_number = @P0 
ORDER BY sl.order_number
```

Comment: As all the `order_number` returned will be the same in this case due to the `WHERE` clause and this is the only column being selected in this case I don't see the `ORDER BY` adds anything.

Comment: Thanks @D-Shih Your input has helped very well. This is what I see happening but not yet sure on how it is happening. We use Spring JPA and the order_number (varchar datatype) is a normal java String in the Entity. Hibernate trace says that it is binding VARCHAR for order_number but the query text found in the DB says that it is nvarchar. Hence we see implicit conversion happening leading to index scan always.
`co`

Comment: Following is from hibernate log

org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [ORD-AC-OV1PH]

but sys.query_sql_text has

(@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P0 int)select TOP(@P0) shipmentli0_.order_number as col_0_0_ from outbound_service.shipment_line shipmentli0_ inner join outbound_service.shipment shipmenten1_ on shipmentli0_.shipment_id=shipmenten1_.id where shipmentli0_.order_number=@P1 and shipmenten1_.fulfillment_center_id=@P2

Comment: When looked at the query plans, The values provided in the where clause have N prefixed. Because the RHS has the nvarchar input, LHS also is converted to nvarchar input. I see that Java driver by default uses nvarchar values as input. To overcome this, I will try using the Type annotion on the order_number field in the Entity class. I will update the outcome. A permanent fix probably would be to convert the varchar columns to nvarchar if UTF characters are to be supported..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final answer after digging a bit into Hibernate, SQL Driver code, Using SQL Profiler to understand the impact on queries. HIbernate logs do not give any clue about the VARCHAR conversion to NVARCHAR. It is the MS SQL Driver by default passing all String variables in JPA Entity as nvarchar inputs into SQL where clause even though the underlying mapped columns are just varchars. This was forcing SQL Engine to do implicit conversion of the column data also into nvarchar.

**Solution:**
Passing in **sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;** in the connection URL would change the driver's default behavior. By default all Entity Strings will be varchars in the query where clause. If there is a need for nvarchar and the driver not taking it into account automatically, the specific field in the entity can be annotated with **@Nationalized** annotation provided by Hibernate. Hibernate would help set the right expectation in this case to the SQL Driver.

sendStringParametersAsUnicode set to false is helpful if we have too many varchar columns that would not need to store international language characters and we refer to such columns heavily in where clause. This would help avoid index scans.